# android- record audio and send it over tcp and play it at the other side

Tags: android, audio

I want to write a simple tcp app that records audio from one side, at the end send the audio over a tcp socket to another side so that the other end user can hear that audio. I record the audio:

Sending Side:

```
        buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(32000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 32000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
    buffer = new byte[buffersize];                 
    audioRecord.startRecording();
            while (isRecording == true) {
                audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                recordedBytes.add(buffer);
            }
            byte[] tmp = new byte[buffersize * recordedBytes.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < recordedBytes.size(); i++) {
                System.arraycopy(recordedBytes.get(i), 0, tmp, i * buffersize, recordedBytes.get(i).length);
   bufferedOutputStream1.writeObject(tmp);
            }
```

and play it at this way:

Receiving Side:

```
        buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(32000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 32000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    atrack.setPlaybackRate(32000);
        atrack.play();
    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[] tmp = serialize(bufferedInputStream.readObject());
            atrack.write(tmp, 0, tmp.length);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

serialize:

```
    public byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws Exception{
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
}
```

but I just hear noise, whats wrong?!!!

Comment: Can you start telling which of that code is used on the sending side and which on the receiving side.

Comment: Why are you using writeObject() for a byte array? I think you could better use .write(). On the receiving side just read the bytes in a byte buffer. You do not need function serialise then.

Comment: @greenapps because i dont know how many bytes is going to be written

Comment: Please explain as i see no problems sendig that byte buffer. You know how many you copied into the buffer. `int nbyteswritten = bufferedOutputStream1.write(tmp, tmp.length());`. Put in a loop until all bytes written.